# Reading text file: Read multiple values if present

Tags: c++, file-io

I am having issues trying to get the program to read to the end of a line in a text file.

I am trying to read data from a text file (one item per line) with the following format (space-separated fields):

- house (12345)
- type (A = Auto or M = motorcylce)
- license (WED123)
- year (2012)
- msrp (23443)

The data will be used to calculate vehicle registration total.

At the moment the program is reading all the lines which are formatted as above, however a house could have *more than one vehicle*, therefore there is additional data on the line (all but the first fields are repeated in this case). 
For example:

```
111111 A QWE123 2012 13222 M RTW234 2009 9023

//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//        first vehicle      second vehicle
```

Once I reach a line which has the additional data, the program does not read it and goes into an infinite loop. How can I read the additional data in the line to get to the end of the file and stop the program from an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>        
#include <iostream>           
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()                   // Function Header
{                             // Start Function
    int house;
    char  type; 
    string license; 
    int year, msrp ; 
    char ch; 

    ifstream inData; 
    ofstream outData; 

    inData.open("register.txt"); 
    outData.open("vehicle.txt"); 

    inData >> house;               // Priming Read

    while (inData) {             // Test file stream variable

        do { 
            inData >> type;         
            inData >> license; 
            inData >> year;
            inData >> msrp; 

            outData << house << type << license << year << msrp << endl; 

            ch = inData.peek();
            inData >> house;

        } while(ch != '\n');            // Check for end of line 

    }                              // End while 

    system ("Pause");      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C? Really? `using namespace std;`?

Comment: Have you tried using `fscanf`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will have a hard time detecting the end of the line. When it tries to read the "extra data" but encounters the next line instead, an error occurs on the stream, preventing you from being able to read again.

You can "fix" your program by not reading the `house` value in the inner loop. Instead, read it after you have detected the end of line.

```
        ch = inData.peek();
        //inData >> house;          // WRONG: house might be next vehicle type

    } while(ch != '\n');            // Check for end of line 

    inData >> house;                // CORRECT

}                              // End while
```

However, a better way to handle this may be to use `getline` and `istringstream`. First get an entire line of input with `getline`. Place the input into an `istringstream`. Then, get the rest of the data from that. See M. M.'s version for an illustration of this.

Comment: Thanks user315052, I appreciate your explanation.